# Is there any way to get max number of used columns in xlsx using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have to get max used column for my work in an uploaded `xlsx`, How can I get it in Node.js?

I have tried multiple packages but didn't succeed.

```
const stream = fs.createReadStream(this.getFile().path);
stream.on('data', (data) => {
    const chunkData = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'buffer' });
    console.log('chunk====', chunkData.Sheets);
});
```

Suppose I have 1 column in the first row and the max 10 column in the nth row, so I want to get the max column i.e; 10

Comment: Is there data in all 10 column in nth row ?

Comment: No there can be some column blank